# Is Windows Workflow Foundation compliance with WfMC Standard?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is Windows Workflow Foundation compliance with WfMC Standard?

http://www.wfmc.org/wfmc-standards-framework.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing different concepts and so your question doesn't make sense.

XPDL, just like BPEL, BPMN, among other standards, are no more than notations developed to represent workflows through text (usually XML) or graphically, using diagrams.

**That being said, WF4 is an .NET API which sits *below* standards**, allowing you to implement any chosen standard, such as WfMC Standard: XPDL.

WF4, also in comparison with WF3, is a highly flexible and extensible API which gives you the freedom, at least in theory, to implement every type of workflows you can imagine with more or less code, depending on the task you want to achieve, and supporting scenarios ranging from human workflow (this is a case-scenario where WF4 is *really* good, because with workflows that can take days, weeks or even months, its persistence implementation is almost transparent to the developer) to system centric workflows (for example small workflows that can be called as WebServices). Services like workflow monitoring are also easily implemented.

All this with a workflow designer which is implemented natively within VS-2010 and that can be rehosted on any .NET application just like any other UI-Control and which translates said workflows to XAML automatically.

I hope you have perceived the difference of the two concepts because you can't really expect WF4 to follow any Workflow Definition Standard when it is just an API.

Comment: While learning, [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en) was my best friend.